# Validation two length options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm validating the model field `number`.

I try to achieve that only `numbers` that are `8` or `6` characters long are allowed.

But with this code i get a error:

**Code:**

```
validates :number, length: { is: [6,8] }
```

**Error:**

```
ArgumentError (:is must be a nonnegative Integer or Infinity):
  app/models/patient.rb:6:in `<class:Patient>'
  app/models/patient.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  app/controllers/patients_controller.rb:38:in `create'
```

How should i change my code? Thanks

Comment: Maybe something like `validates :number, length: { inclusion: { in: [6, 8] } }`

Comment: @freemanoid sorry but this wont work! Maybe a custom validation?

Comment: Custom validator is an obvious and simple solution. I believe you don't need to ask on SO to solve you problem that way.

Answer (score 0):

A custom validation might look something like:

```
class PatientValidator
  def validate(patient)
    patient.errors.add(:number, "Bad length!") unless [6, 8].include? patient.number
  end
end
```

Then, in Patient:

```
validates_with PatientValidator
```